# get name of memory mapped file

Tags: windows, memory-leaks, ram, sysinternals

I have a windows host where, according to rammap, almost all memory is in mapped files. I try to find out which file causes such leak. All available guides suggest using tab File Summary to find out connection between file and mapped files. But there is no any file which occupies such amount of mapped files memory.

Is there a way to find out which file is to blame? I guess sysinternals tools like rammap already use windows api functions, so i won't find out more info if i'll try to use functions like `GetMappedFileNameA` on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I have 24 GB of mapped files on my 96 GB machine. It seems to me that this is simply the Windows file cache ("Smartdrv", if you know that from DOS times).

[image: RAMMap]

This is roughly the same amount as displayed in Task Manager as "cached". The tool tip of that reads as

> Memory that contains cached data and code that is not actively in use.

[image: Task Manager]

So, this is nothing to worry about. In fact it's great, because Windows can read files from memory instead of disk. That makes stuff much faster.